# Add Chart to changing data table

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I have a code that will create a new sheet and table and add all of the collected data into the table. I want to also had a chart at the bottom of the table. I used the record macro to get the basics of the coding to add the table, the problem is the data is constantly changing. The columns and rows expand and extract depending on the amount of data collected for the day.

How do I code it so that the data collected expands the chart as well here: `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("B8:AG8")` and here: `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master log'!$B$2:$AG$2"`. The ranges need to be able to expand or reduce depending on the table data.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks!

**What I have compiled so far:**

```
intLastCol = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
intLastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 4").IncrementLeft -26.25
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 4").IncrementTop 80.25
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ListObjects("Stats").ListRows(1)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Continuing Total Stats"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master log'!" & ListObjects("Stats").ListRows(1).Address
```

Comment: Depending on what kind of control you have over the data, you could define a named range for the cells in the sheet and then set the chart source to the named range.

Comment: I have full control. What do you mean defining the named range? The range changes every time the macro is called depending on the amount and type of data. Can I make a defined named range when the range changes and how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's actual *table* you can use [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223938%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in your macro. Specificaly the [ListRows Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177921%28v=office.12%29.aspx).
So for example you could use something like this:
`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ListObjects("TableName").listRows(1)`
and
`ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master log'!" & ListObjects("TableName").listRows(1).address`

You may need to specify the sheet on which the listobject is located. Like `sheets("SummarySheet").listobjects("TableName"). ...`

---

## Edit 1

### Without table

Presuming the upper left most cell is "A1" or in other words `cells(1,1)` and that headers are filled every time, you can use this to determine the last column and use that as a column index.
`intLastCol = cells(1,1).End(xlToRight).column`

You can get the range of one row using following line :
`set rngOneRowInRange = range(cells(1,1),cells(1,intLastCol))`
**Notes :** You may (and probably should) change the row indexes to your situation. Which row you want to use in chart...

### With table

You can use [ListObjects.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211863%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You will have to determine the whole range for the table (the *Source* parameter) using similar methods described in the **Without table** section.
To determine last row you can use 
`intLastRow = cells(1,1).End(xlDown).row` (this presumes there are no, and never will be, blank cells in column "A")

Then you can use my original proposed solution with `.listRows(1)`

## Edit 2

The syntax for manipulating with chart using table range looks like this :

```
Sub InsertChart()
    Dim shpMyChart As Shape
    Dim strRangeAddress As String

    Set shpMyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered)
    strRangeAddress = Sheets("Master log").ListObjects("Stats").ListRows(1).Range.Address

    With shpMyChart
        .Name = "MyMacroChart"
        .Left = 300
        .Top = 150

        With .Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master log'!" & strRangeAddress)
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Continuing Total Stats"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ("'Master log'!" & strRangeAddress) 'possibly a duplicate of SetSourceData, I'm not sure
        End With '.Chart

    End With 'shpMyChart

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh no, you're right it's actually not a named table because the data is created every time and just entered in the cell ranges and looks like a table, but it's not an actual table that is created. Is there any work around for that?

Comment: There are workarounds. **Alt1** You can convert the range to table using VBA. **Alt2** You can get the ranges without table, using `.End` and maybe `.Resize` and `.Offset`.

Comment: I think the first option would be the best. How would I convert the range into a table?

Comment: @Lilly see the **Edit 1** and **With table** section in my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the code with the advice you gave me but I'm getting an error saying that sub or function is not defined and it's highlighting the `.ListObjects` I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. This is what I have so far as edited in my question.

Comment: @Lilly almost, just missing the worksheet reference for the listobjects. [ListObjects Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223942%28v=office.12%29.aspx). My bad, didn't notice it before.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Maybe I'm just not actually writing the entire code correctly from start to finish.

Comment: Am I possibly missing a reference?

Comment: @Lilly I added Edit 2, maybe this will help.